# Unable to use Visual Studio project on different computer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer, codedom

I was working on a project (winforms, C++/Cli) on my desktop. When I copy project files to use it in my laptop, designer do not open. 
 
 References to the 3rd party library[[MetroFramework](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui)] is properly linked (project compile & run fine, no build error)
 but if I open designer I receive the following error

> C++ CodeDom parser error: Line:99,Column:27 --unknown type".please
>   make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. if
>   this is a part of your development project, make sure that the project
>   has been successfully built"

code at line 99:

```
this->metroTabControl1 = (gcnew MetroFramework::Controls::MetroTabControl());
```

**Note:** In designer, if I click on `ignore & Continue`, I get plain win form. Here if I drag & drop MetroFramework's UI control (metroTabControl) it display's fine. but if i close & reopen designer again i see the same error!!

Tried few suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853922/why-does-visual-c-designer-not-work-after-i-added-a-control-to-my-form) & [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/794a929a-c8a3-48fc-99f0-cc635932e6cb/c-codedom-parser-error-internal-error?forum=winformsdesigner), none of them worked!

Comment: try reinstalling library via NuGet also make sure your installing the right assembly

Comment: Thanks for your comment. visual studio is actually pointing to all the libraries that i have referenced. 
i'm using few 3rd party libraries from code project which are not available in NuGet.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all toolbox items and references. Provide full path in vcproj. Remove and then connect the respective DLL required.